# service worker showNotification require interaction flag

Tags: service-worker, web-push, push-api, web-notifications

the below code generates a notification which automatically goes away in 20 secs on chrome ..
I don't get why this is happening ...!!!
the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification) says that default timeout value of notification is 8 secs , then why it takes 20 secs to dismiss the notif,,,

and i know the require_interaction flag is not stable but ...do any of you have any idea as to if it works with only a specific chrome version etc ...!

```
self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: icon,
        tag: tag,
        data: notificationData,
        vibrate: vibrate,
        requireInteration:'true'
```

Update the issue was requireInteraction flag spelling .. ..my bad ...!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timeout in the implementation is indeed 20 seconds so the documentation should probably be fixed.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ui/message_center/message_center_style.cc&cl=GROK&l=60&rcl=1452142029

require interaction should be stable already. It shipped in M47 which is the stable version as far as I know.

http://blog.chromium.org/2015/10/chrome-47-beta-idle-time-work-splash.html

Also note that the flag is called requireInteraction (with a C) the msdn doc seems wrong there as well.

Edit: Note that as chrome moves to native (OS provided) notifications the timeout is now defined by the underlying OS. For example in MacOS is 5 seconds. Different versions of linux and Windows 10 (once Chrome switches to native notifications in that platform) will be different as well.

Comment: And I just went ahead and updated mdn while at it :)

Comment: my chrome ver no is Version 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)...can you think of any reason as to why the notification doesn't stick around ...!!!and why the requireInterAction flag is not working in my case ?

Comment: Works for me in the same version (linux and Mac) can you go to https://tests.peter.sh/notification-generator/ and display a notification there with the require interaction box ticked? If it sticks it's probably an issue with your code :)

Comment: Oh and try requireInteration: true (without the quotes)

Comment: your test page notification works for me in my chrome ,...!!

Comment: there must be something in my code , i tried without the quotes  true , even that is not working ... probably i might have called dismiss notifications some where let me double check

Comment: yeah the without quotes was just to make it sane. javascript will interpret any non empty string as true.

Comment: notice i copied the flag name requireInteration from the same document  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification   notice the missing 'c' in requireInteraction ,,, is it right ?? is that the flag ??

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that as well. requireInteraction is the correct spelling

Comment: on OS X it's 5s default

Comment: I updated the answer, the actual timeout length is not reliable anymore since most browsers are now using the underlying OS notification platform which defines their own timeouts